# Responsive design scrolling issues on Android

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am converting my website into a responsive design. It is looking excellent, except for one annoying issue. My slideshow keeps on jumping around the website as I scroll on my Android device. It works just fine though on the iPhone, and on the computer.

The script I am using for my slideshow is http://swipejs.com/

Is this a common issue?

Comment: Which one is your device? Because i haven't seen any issue regarding this plugin. Try to use overflow:hidden; for your outer parent or body